# Remove broken java installation (linux)

Tags: linux, apt-get

I somehow messed up my Java installation and now I get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove jre1.8.0_66
(Reading database ... 55212 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jre1.8.0-65 ...
find: `/usr/java/*': No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jre1.8.0-65.postrm: line 586: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing jre1.8.0-65 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jre1.8.0-65
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I force to remove this? The folder with the java files is empty, but this shows up everytime i install something...

EDIT: Linux says it's half installed/removed:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
> ```

There is no `/usr/sbin/alternatives` in Debian, Ubuntu, or their clones.
Instead, there is `/usr/bin/update-alternatives`.

I suggest a temporary symbolic link to work around the badly converted RPM package:

```
mkdir -p /usr/sbin
ln -s /usr/bin/update-alternatives /usr/sbin/alternatives
```

Answer (score 3):

**Verify avaialble installations in your machine : -**

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java

There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).  


     Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
    ------------------------------------------------------------
      0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java   3         auto mode
    * 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java   3         manual mode
      2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java   2         manual mode
      3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1         manual mode

    Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

**Now remove existing symbolic links first**

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java"
```

-------javac

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/javac   3         auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/javac   3         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/javac  2         manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/javac  1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

**Now remove symbolic links**

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/javac"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/javac"
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/javac"
```

--if you see any issue with javaws than follow same steps to remvoe

Its time to set the symbolic links to your location, download the linux java version which you like and move the unziped directories to 
proper location like /usr/lib/jvm/ which common naming standard insted of one which you got from site name like java-6-oracle

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/javaws
```

Same like whichever the version you want just run above commands after placing in required location.

Change the jave version by using sudo update-alternatives --config java and selete the options.

leave the comment if any assistence required.

Comment: Its easy resolve the broken link by following these steps and it will also helps to fix other symbolic links as well

Comment: you might need to install the alternatives executable first, with command like: sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/your_JDK/jdk1.8.0_332/bin/javac 1