# Requirements check failed for JDK 8

Tags: cordova, java-8

I have installed JDK 8 on my Cordova prodejct.
When i run the yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk, i get this:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.lysator.liu.se
 * epel: ftp.lysator.liu.se
 * extras: ftp.lysator.liu.se
 * remi-php55: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-php56: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-php72: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-safe: remi.schlundtech.de
 * updates: ftp.lysator.liu.se
Package 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

my java version is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

when i run : alternatives --config java
There are 2 programs which provide java.

```
  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
   2           java-11-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.3.7-0.el7_6.x86_64/bin/java)
```

in my bash_profile:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

so everything looks ok here.

but when i run cordova run android, I get this:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.3
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

I really need help.

UPPDATE:
Now i have try this:

javac-version : javac 11.0.3

$JAVA_HOME, alternatives --config java

```
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java,: No such file or directory
```

cordova build android

```
config file undefined requested for changes not found at /home/Desktop/freetocollect/platforms/android/undefined, ignoring
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.3
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

**UPPDATE 2**

Now i have tryed to do this the right way.

echo $JAVA_HOME

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

which java

```
/usr/bin/java
```

java -version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

alternatives --config java

```
*+ 2 java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
```

when i run cordova requirements i get this:

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: not installed 
Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK version 8 installed.
You can get it from the following location:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1
Gradle: not installed 
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: not installed 
Cordova tooling for iOS requires Apple macOS
Some of requirements check failed

Please help.

**uppdate 20/6**

I type the command :

```
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

And the path was right.

**then i type:**

```
update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

then i get failed to create /var/lib/alternatives/java.new: Permission denied

So I run it with sudo before code, and i think it works. no error.

**when i type cordova android build i get:**

```
config file undefined requested for changes not found at /home/platforms/android/undefined, ignoring
Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK version 8 installed.
You can get it from the following location:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

I dont now what to do.

**uppdate**

now i have manage to fix some errors when i run cordova requirements:

```
Android target: not installed 
avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1
Gradle: not installed 
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: not installed 
Cordova tooling for iOS requires Apple macOS
```

now to the next error.

**UPPDATE: 21/6**

i have fix some errors, Butt still have som left.
Sow i dont now how to fix them.

```
$ cordova build android
config file undefined requested for changes not found at /home/xxxxxxxxx/platforms/android/undefined, ignoring
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/xxxxxxxxx/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

/opt/gradle/gradle-5.1/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Common problem in a number of difference contexts - several Linux distros install OpenJDK 11, and several Linux scripts fail to check for a a "best fit" among the installed JDKs.  It sounds like Cordova is among the latter.  Look here for options: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater/68734/20

Comment: i remove everything with jvm, did an update, run sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk..get answer Package 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64 already installed and latest version.... HELP

Comment: Please update your post: 1) Describe what you did (e.g. how exactly did you "remove everything"?). 2) Re-print output of `$JAVA_HOME`, `alternatives --config java` and `javac -version`.  3) Re-run `cordova build android` and copy/paste the output.

Comment: how can i remove everything and install it again.

Comment: You said "i remove everything".  *What exactly does that mean???* Please update your post and tell us.  Please update your post with 1) 2) and 3) above.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  You still haven't explained "i remove everything"..., but it's clear 1) you still have Java 11 (it's your default "java"), and 2) "alternatives java" is completely messed up (it used to have 11 and 8, now it has nothing).  SUGGESTION: 1) Verify you have OpenJDK 8 (`apt-get` reinstall with "-force", if you need to), then 2) `update-alternatives --set java /path/to/java8/jre`.  Here are two links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635075 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100732/

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer me, i dont remember what i search for, but it remove it...and now nothing works. i will follow your answer and see what happends.

Comment: That's a good plan.  It looks like you've inadvertently trashed either/both Java 11 and Java 8.  Specifically: 1) Force-install JDK 8 (e.g. `sudo apt-get -f install openjdk-8-jdk`), then 2) ensure "alternatives" points to JDK8's JRE: `update-alternatives --set java /path/to/java8/jre`.  Remember:Although JDK 11 and JDK8 can co-exist on the same host, Cordova apparently needs your "default" to be Java 8.

Comment: I run : sudo update-alternatives --config java, and get this: *+ 1           java-11-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.3.7-0.el7_6.x86_64/bin/java), i need it to be java 8..how can i remove every java and install it again..work on centos7

Comment: i check: rpm -aq | grep -i jdk, and it shows this files..java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.3.7-0.el7_6.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64
java-11-openjdk-devel-11.0.3.7-0.el7_6.x86_64
copy-jdk-configs-3.3-10.el7_5.noarch
java-11-openjdk-11.0.3.7-0.el7_6.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64

Comment: Ah... *Centos*!  I assumed you were probably on Ubuntu ("apt-get"), not Centos ("yum").  1) Try this: `su -c "yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk"`. 2) At this point, you should now have Java 8.  3) Run `alternatives --config java` to verify you have both Java 8 and 11.  4) If Java 8 isn't the default, then run `update-alternatives --set java /path/to/java8/jre`.  NOTE: if "yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk" complains, you can try `yum reinstall java-1.8.0-openjdk`.

Comment: is this the path to java: java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java)

Comment: No, the path you need for "update alternatives" is `update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre`.  This should create some symbolic links.  At that point, `alternatives --config java` and `java -version` should both show Java 8.

Comment: i tryed you code, i get this: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre has not been configured as an alternative for java

Comment: Sigh.  I was wrong: you actually need `update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java` (like you said in the first place).  TYPE THIS FIRST: `ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java` (to ensure the path is correct).  Please also look here: https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-centos-7/.  Update your post: copy/paste a) what commands you type, b) the output from those commands.

Comment: it doesent work, i have uppdate my topic